# Can anyone tell me what I had to be careful with and how I can reinstall grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I might install a 2nd linux system on my HD. I was told that I would have to reinstall grub to make the 2 system appear after I turn on my laptop.
I also have widows installed...so it might get a bit messy.

I have just watched this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I 
And it is really informative, but I need a proper walkthrough to understand how this grub thingy works. Can anyone redirect me to a video or webpage where someone explains this grub installation in case of secondary linux OS in details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of one distro that you install as being the "main" one. Let's assume it's your current Ubuntu. Your goal is to keep this copy of grub in place.

In order to keep the copy of grub installed by the main distro in place, don't install a new bootloader over it when doing additional installs. This is actually very simple, but may seem tricky the first time you do it.

1. Use the manual partitioner during the install.

   Every modern installer will provide an opportunity to set up your own partition scheme. In Ubuntu, this is the *Something Else* option.
2. You will also be given the chance to say where (or if) a new bootloader should be installed.

   If you have the option to not install the bootloader at all, choose that.

   If you are forced to choose a location, *do not* choose `/dev/sda`. This is the location of grub in your main distro.

   Instead, choose the partition where you are installing `/`, for example `/dev/sda5` or whatever the number is.
3. Reboot back into you main distro and run `sudo update-grub` so grub can see the new install.

You only need to [reinstall grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) if you make a mistake and accidentally install a new bootloader to `/dev/sda`. If this happens, relax. This is another one of those things that is really very easy but seems tricky until you have done it.